# Оптимизация Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, drag-n-drop

Вычитал [на сайте о оптимизации Drag and Dorp в javascript](https://javascript.ru/ui/draganddrop++). Не знаю, как реализовать.

> Иногда красивее и удобнее - визуально перемещать не сам элемент, а его
>   клон или макет. Например, переносимый объект очень сложен, и его
>   передвижение целиком тормозит браузер и выглядит
>   громоздко/неэстетично.
>
> Сам элемент при этом скрывается display/visibility='none' или просто
>   остается на месте, в зависимости от логики интерфейса.
>
> Переносимый клон инициализуется в начале переноса и уничтожается в
>   конце.

Comment: Я не читал статью и из приложенной вами цитаты совершенно ничего не понятно. Возможно автор имел ввиду, что если  обьект состоит из множества деталей(dom-элементов), то имеет смысл, во время клика по нему , прятать его и под курсор "подлаживать" его изображение, которое будет двигаться за курсором с помощью трансформаций...т.е сам обьект будет менять свое положение лишь раз, что значительно уменьшит нагрузку на процессор, так как не нужно будет пересчитывать положение всех его составных частей по ходу движения за курсором мыши

Comment: Написал и подумал: а пересчитывает ли браузер позицию всех вложенных элементов если я двигаю родительский? Кто знает?

Comment: Т.е, если я задам родительскому элемету -100px, применятся ли эти значение неявно ко всем вложенным элементам ?

Answer (score 1):

**Теоретически**, можно сделать скриншот DOM ноды и динамично подменить.

**Практически**, я создал около пятиста вложенных flex контейнеров с центровкой и на моем ноутбуке 2012 года все отлично работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drag and drop</title>
    <style>
      .red { background-color: red; }
      .green { background-color: green; }
      .blue { background-color: blue; }
      .root { position: fixed; }
      .box {
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        justify-content: stretch;
        padding: 2px;
      }
      .box > * {
        flex: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      (function() {
        const generateDraggable = (side = 500) => {
          const root = document.createElement('div');
          root.className = "red box root";
          [root.style.height, root.style.width] = new Array(2).fill(`${side}px`);
          let parent = root;
          for (let i = 0; i !== parseInt(side / 4); i += 1) {
            const child = document.createElement('div');
            const color = i % 2 === 0 ? 'red' : i % 3 === 0 ? 'green' : 'blue';
            child.className = `${color} box`;
            parent.appendChild(child);
            parent = child;
          }
          document.body.appendChild(root);
          document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            const [x, y] = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
            [root.style.top, root.style.left] = [`${y}px`, `${x}px`];
            console.log(x, y);
          });
        };
        generateDraggable();
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Посмотреть онлайн можно [тут](https://gist.github.com/tripolskypetr/843f557c55f416db526ccb0e62fd9f5c)

Comment: Здравствуйте , вы написали отличный код , но к сожалению он не решает мою проблему , так как если попытаться повернуть данную конструкцию то ничего не выйдет.